# Create a new feature for a WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a page with a specific title to launch the template I designed.

For this purpose, I added the following code to the functions.php file and it created a new page for me:

```
$check_page_exist = get_page_by_title('Login', 'OBJECT', 'page'); 

if(empty($check_page_exist)) {
    $page_id = wp_insert_post(
        array(
        'comment_status' => 'close', 
        'ping_status'    => 'close', 
        'post_author'    => 1, 
        'post_title'     => ucwords('Login'), 
        'post_name'      => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', trim('Login'))), 
        'post_status'    => 'publish', 
        'post_content'   => ' ', 
        'post_type'      => 'page', 
        'post_parent'    => ' ',
        )
    );
}
```

But I have changed the attribute of the page and added the template (Login Page) to the page using the following code:

```
 <?php
    // template name: Login Page
  ?>
```

Now I want the page that I created with the above code to be replaced with this template instead of the default template.

Is there a way to change the page layout by editing the code?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/84395

Comment: The problem with these codes is that they change the properties of all pages, but I only want to change this one page.

Comment: What are you talking about, both those statements shown there update meta data for _one_ single post id?

Comment: I just want to do this by adding one line of code (for example: `post-attribute => "Login Page"` or something like that). Is this possible or not?

Comment: wp_insert_post sets values that are stored directly in the wp_posts table. Meta data is stored in the wp_postmeta table, so you can not set it using wp_insert_post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $check_page_exist = get_page_by_title( 'Custom', 'OBJECT', 'page' );
    $template_slug    = 'template-test.php'; // Replace with the desired template file name.

    if ( empty( $check_page_exist ) ) {
        $page_id = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'comment_status' => 'close',
                'ping_status'    => 'close',
                'post_author'    => 1,
                'post_title'     => ucwords( 'Custom' ),
                'post_name'      => strtolower( str_replace( ' ', '-', trim( 'Custom' ) ) ),
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_content'   => ' ',
                'post_type'      => 'page',
                'post_parent'    => ' ',
                'page_template'  => $template_slug,
            )
        );
    }
```